# flash/xml based slideshow not displaying images

Tags: php, javascript, flash, slideshow

I'm trying to figure out why the slideshow on [this page](http://credencegasservices.com/cgs.php?ID=17) is not working (it only works on FireFox, doesn't work on Chrome or IE).

As you can see, this is flash-based slideshow and reads its data from xml. The xml is also generated using a php script.

I can verify that the correct xml is generated when I manually navigate to the [php script](http://www.credencegasservices.com/slideshow-xml.php?showID=8) giving it the right slidehsow ID.

That php script is called in the flashvars property of the embed code. Any idea why the slideshow is not displayed?

Here is the entire code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','680','height','251','src','topShow','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','topShow','FlashVars','xmlfile=http://www.credencegasservices.com/slideshow-xml.php?showID=8' ); //end AC code
</script>
<embed width="680" height="251" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="xmlfile=http://www.credencegasservices.com/slideshow-xml.php?showID=8" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" quality="high" src="topShow.swf">
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="680" height="251">
    <param name="FlashVars" value="xmlfile=http://www.credencegasservices.com/slideshow-xml.php?showID=8" />
    <param name="movie" value="topShow.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <embed src="topShow.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="680" height="251" FlashVars="xmlfile=http://www.credencegasservices.com/slideshow-xml.php?showID=8"></embed>
    </object>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Your code looks right to me. What version of ActionScript are you using? Have you tried loading the file from a local directory instead of a URL? Have you tried doing a Trace in Flash? This site seems to have some helpful tips: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/87635-using-flashvars-in-as2-and-as3/

Comment: are your images in same folder as swf?

Comment: Images are not in the same folder as swf, but the swf and xml are in the same folder.